# SUMIFS and multiple lookups within array

Tags: excel, excel-2007

I'm trying to use the SUMPRODUCT formula to get the sum of money (O - number) from specific weeks (C - date) and rooms (E - text) when used by organizer (A - text).

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A2:A3000=S2);--(E2:E3000=R2);--(WEEKNUM(C2:C3000)=3);O2:O3000)
```

This works well when looking up one organizer at a time.

How can I modify this formula to look up several organizers at once? Organizers are listed in S2:S10.

I'm thinking something like the following:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A2:A3000=S2 OR S3 etc.);--(E2:E3000=R2);--(WEEKNUM(C2:C3000)=3);O2:O3000)
```

Also - Can this be done in an easy and neat way with the faster SUMIFS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use MATCH like this

`=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2:A3000;S2:S10;0));--(E2:E3000=R2);--(WEEKNUM(C2:C3000+0)=3);O2:O3000)`

For SUMIFS you'll need a helper column for the week number......

With week number in column Z try

`=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(O:O;A:A;S2:S10;E:E;R2;Z:Z;3))`

Assumes no repeats in S2:S10 or you'll double count. Note that SUMPRODUCT merely sums the array created by SUMIFS (an array of nine values because of S2:S10) - that latter function does the hard work so it should be faster

BTW I'm not sure your original formula will work because WEEKNUM doesn't normally accept a range....but it does except an array hence the +0 in my version.....

Comment: Works like a charm. My bad on the +0. Could you explain why +0 allows it to be accepted as an array?

Comment: No problem - C2:C3000 is obviously a range but when you perform some sort of calculation on it, either using a function or operator that will convert it to an array, e.g. YEAR(C2:C3000) or C2:C3000+0 as I used above. Obviously you want the operation to leave the value unchanged so adding zero or multiplying by 1 will do that. In Excel 2003 WEEKNUM doesn't accept an array or a range but in later versions it accepts arrays only hence the need to convert to an array (note: this can be problematic if the range contains any text because using +0 will give you a #VALUE! error and formula will fail)